# "Proper" way to (web) proxy in Java

Tags: java, http, proxy

So far my research has found four distinct ways to make Java use proxies:

- Command line parameters such as -Dhttp.proxyHost
- System properties such as System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost","110.11.12.30");
- URLConnection(Proxy proxy)
- urlConnection.setRequestProperty(...

Which one is the proper/recommended way to specify proxies (ignoring specific outside requirements that might make one way more attractive than the others) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to rely on Java's URLConnecion, I'd pick option three.

Comment: I like green the best of all colours. Can you explain or back up your advice ?

Comment: Yes, this option gives me the full flexibility to control the proxy setup. Option one and two always change the entire VM which might not be desired in a shared VM like in Tomcat uses. Option four is unknown to me. Since when can I set the proxy as a request property? This is weird.

Answer (score 1):

There is also a system property to inherit the proxy settings from the system:

```
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
```